# Upload multiple files in sails.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to upload multiple files in sails framework. Below is the code

```
req.file('photos').upload(function (err, uploadedPhotos) {
  if (err) return res.serverError(err);
  async.eachSeries(uploadedPhotos, 
    function (uploadedFile, callback) {
      sails.log("upload file size and name is " + uploadedFile.size + " " + uploadedFile.filename);

      req.file(uploadedFile).upload({
        dirname: "path/to/directory",
        // saveAs: function (file, cb) { cb(null, file.filename); }
      },
      function onUploadComplete(err, files) {
          if (err) return res.serverError(err);

          if (files.length === 0) {
            return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');
          }
          sails.log("files uploaded");
      });
    }, function (err) {
      // if any of the saves produced an error, err would equal that error
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        return res.send("ok");
      }
    });
});
```

It always shows No file was uploaded.

Edit : My html file code

```
<form action="/file_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="photos" id="photos" accept='image/*' multiple>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sails.js form post not submitting any data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764633/sails-js-form-post-not-submitting-any-data)

Comment: @lependu My files are at the end of the input form.

Comment: Where do you use the `skipper` module? I do not see it in your code.

Comment: skipper is inbuilt is sailsjs. refer : https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-file

Comment: First I would consider using an Ajax-form since Sails has integrated with vue so completely. If you decide to do that I would take a look at formatting your `action` on your `ejs` a bit differently. 
Here's a recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52718030/sailsjs-get-resonse-of-ajax-form-of-sailsjs-in-the-submitted-function

Comment: Were you able to fix this TechTeam? @lependu - that files being at end of input form is a bug from 2015, has it not yet been fixed?